# Jqplot pie- charts doesn't utilize the full width and height of the div container

Tags: charts, width, jqplot

Just noticed that the pie-chart that is displayed is not utilizing the full width and height of the container.

I can see some blank spaces. Attached image below.

[image]

I have drawn borders to the div. And it is clear that the pie isn't utilizing the full width and height.

How do i get this thing fixed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can anyone sort this out??

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the default piechart renderer has a padding of 20px. Reduce it as you see fit by adjusting the padding such as:

```
jQuery("#'. $id .'").jqplot([your data here],
       {
          seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
              padding: 10
            }
       }
});
```

Comment: Hi will. Thank you for the answer. But it didn't help.

Comment: It worked for me, can you edit your question with more of your code?